# Create new File on build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a project that use Jenkinsfile to do some tasks, one of them is generate build version of project with the version on .jar file name.

Using Java 8 and build.gradle i was doing like this

- Build.gradle

  ```
  ext {
      buildVersion = '1.0.0'
  }

  task readImageVersion() {
       doLast {
           new File("image.version").text = "Version=${buildVersion}"
       }
  }
  ```
- Read this file to get version on Jenkinsfile

  ```
  script {
       def props = readProperties file: 'image.version'
       def version = props['Version']
  }
  ```

Now i'm using Java 17 and build.gradle.kts and i can't find a way to do something like this.
Can someone help?

I thy to do something like this, but miserable fails

```
task("readImageVersion") {
     File.createTempFile(version as String, ".txt")
}
```

Comment: What does "miserable fails" look like? What error do you get? What have you done to try and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build.gradle.kts` equivalent of the `build.gradle` snippet in the question would be something like below:

```kotlin
extra.apply {
    set("buildVersion", "1.0.0")
}

tasks.register("readImageVersion") {
     doLast {
         file("image.version").appendText("""Version=${project.property("buildVersion")}""")
     }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work too

Comment: Are you getting some error when you run the `readImageVersion` task?

Comment: This is my script on Jenkinsfile to get this file:

            steps {
                script {
                    def props = readProperties file: 'image.version'
                    def version = props['Version']
                    echo 'Building docker image...'
                    echo "Version: ${version}"
                }
            }

And it shows that file image.version does not exist

Comment: The snippet I posted is the kts equivalent of what you had asked in the question. Jenkins not finding the file is probably due to some unrelated reason as you seem to have done multiple changes(Java 8 -> 17, build.gradle -> kts).  Were gradle version and Jenkinsfile contents also changed as part of this? If you share the complete contents of original build.gradle, new build.gradle.kts, Jenkinsfile and gradle version(s) used, I might be able to help - can't be sure

Comment: I improve the question, if you, please, could look this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888151/build-gradle-kts-task-to-return-string