# build.gradle.kts task to return string

Tags: build.gradle

I'm using Java 17 ang build.gradle.kts on a project with a Jenkinsfile pipeline that automatic deploy it on envs.

One of stages on Jenkinsfile is to build docker image and upload it on Nexus, and we add the version on name to internal control.

When we create a new branch, we update the version on build.gradle and in the Jenkinsfile. What i want to do is a task on build.gradle that return the version setted on it that can be use by Jenkinsfile. This way we will set the version only on build.gradle

My current code is:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.sonarqube")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

version = "23.3.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

val springVersion = "3.0.4"
val lombokVersion = "1.18.26"

tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName.set("project-name.jar")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$springVersion")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springVersion")

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")

    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.3.0")

    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.15.2")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.4")

    implementation("org.simpleflatmapper:sfm-springjdbc:8.2.3")

    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.3")

    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final")

    implementation ("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        VERSION = '23.3.1'
    }
    stage('Build Docker image') {
        when {
            expression {
               return env.BRANCH_NAME.find("release/")
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Building docker image...'
                docker.withRegistry('http://localhost:8083', 'nexus-credentials') {
                    def customImage = docker.build("project-name:$VERSION")
                    customImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to remove that environment version set on Jenkinsfile and replace it for a gradle task that will return the version on build.gradle

I already try something like this

```
tasks.register("printVersion") {
    doLast {
        println("version=$version")
    }
}
```

Comment: What gradle version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it worked only printing the version, here's the code

build.gradle

```
version = "1.0.0"

tasks.register("printVersion") {
    println("version=$version")
}
```

Jenkinsfile

```
script {
    def version = sh(
        returnStdout: true,
        script: "./gradlew printVersion | grep version="
    ).substring(8).trim()
    echo "Version: ${version}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With gradle `7.6.1`, I made the below changes. The first two were to get the code to build, the next two were to get the version in the Jenkins file

- Set version to `sonarqube` plugin
- Set `mainClass` in `bootJar` task
- Added a `writeVersionToFile` gradle task to write `project.version` to a file
- Added a Jenkins stage and step to call the gradle task and then read the project version from the file

**build.gradle.kts:**

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    id("org.sonarqube") version "3.5.0.2730"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

version = "23.3.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

val springVersion = "3.0.4"
val lombokVersion = "1.18.26"

tasks.bootJar {
    mainClass.set("io.githb.devatherock.Application")
    archiveFileName.set("project-name.jar")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$springVersion")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springVersion")

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")

    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.3.0")

    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.15.2")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.4")

    implementation("org.simpleflatmapper:sfm-springjdbc:8.2.3")

    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.3")

    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final")

    implementation ("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.register("writeVersionToFile") {
    doLast {
        file("version.properties").appendText("""version=${project.version}""")
    }
}
```

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
def version = ''

pipeline {
    stages {    
        stage('Read Version') { 
            steps { 
                sh """#!/bin/bash   
                    ./gradlew writeVersionToFile    
                """ 
                script {    
                    def props = readProperties file: 'version.properties'   
                    version = props['version']  
                }   
            }   
        }

        stage('Build Docker image') {
            when {
               expression {
                  return env.BRANCH_NAME.find("release/")
               }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Building docker image...'
                    docker.withRegistry('http://localhost:8083', 'nexus-credentials') {
                        def customImage = docker.build("project-name:$version")
                        customImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```